# Modrewrite regex

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL: `http://www.domain.com/keyword/b21?f=&ca1=50&p=1`

And the `RewriteRule` I am trying to use is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/b([0-9]+)?f=([^.]+)&p=([0-9]+)$ script.php?id=$2&p=$2&filters=$3
```

Unfortunately this rule is not matching the URL.

I think it has something to do with the `?` as i know this is a character used in regualr expressions.

Any help would be greatly apprecriated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this, and I've not used a rewrite like this before myself, so it might not be exactly right.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=([^.]+)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/b([0-9]+)$ script.php?id=$2&p=$2&filters=%1
```

Comment: I've looked at the docs for you, and edited my answer to something that hopefully works (or almost works).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you redirect the URL with the full query string and process it directly in the PHP script with [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)